# jQuery LightSlider is not working but in JSFiddle's works very well

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I find it very strange. I couldn't figure it out at all about lightSlider.

First of all, I have put jquery plugin on `<head>`. Something like this below:

```
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/js/lightSlider/lightSlider.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/js/lightSlider/jquery.lightSlider.js" />
</head>
```

Secondly, I have put HTML something like this below:

```
<div class="produk-details-left">
        <ul id="lightSlider">
            <li>
                <img src="pic1.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="pic2.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="pic3.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="pic4.jpg" />
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Lastly, I don't forget to put CSS. Something like this below:

```
.produk-details-left ul {
list-style: none outside none;
padding-left: 0;
margin-bottom:0;
}

.produk-details-left li {
display: block;
float: left;
margin-right: 6px;cursor:pointer;
}

.produk-details-left img {
display: block;
height: auto;
max-width: 100%;
}
```

Lastly, it is working in JSFiddle [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/2patspw2/93/).

In conclusion, it is working in JSFiddle but it doesn't work in my server. The results are it didn't look like an image on the top with thumbnails at the bottom. Looks like my plugin is not working.  I really find it strange. Am I missing something?

**UPDATED**

I changed the `<head>` script again. Still it doesn't work.

```
<head>
   <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
   <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/js/lightSlider/lightSlider.css" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/js/lightSlider/jquery.lightSlider.js" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/js/lightSlider/jquery.lightSlider.min.js" />
</head>
```

Comment: I don't see images on JSFiddle.

Comment: Do you get any errors in your browser's console?  I see nothing wrong with how you have on JSFiddle besides the broken images.  Something is different on your site perhaps.

Comment: Alright @Scott, I just updated Michael Jackson pic. Any ideas on my `<head>` ?

Comment: Looks good on JSFiddle. Something must be different on your server. I'd recommend checking Chrome's developer console via F12.

Comment: @Scott it's the same. No errors in console. I guessed something wrong in the `<head>` I am very sure. Just missing script maybe. I couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

You does not include the script for lightSlider

**Try:**

```
<head>
   <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
   <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script> 
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/js/lightSlider/lightSlider.css" />
   <script src="assets/js/lightSlider/jquery.lightSlider.js" />
</head>
```

Comment: Yes, that's the one. Thank you. But still it doesn't work.. :/

Comment: You may also include your custom script for lightSlider

Comment: I appreciate your answers btw what is custom script? :/

Comment: If you include the script like $('#lightSlider').lightSlider
which is an external file. It will be place under the jquery.lightSlider.js

Comment: Is it? I thought it should be fine since `jquery.lightSlider.js` get that script eventhough it is an external file.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it works after using

```
 $(window).on("load",()=>{
        $("#lightslider").lightSlider({})
}
```

Otherwise the elements with .clone class are not rendered properly.